# JavaFX - Daemon Thread gets suspended without error message

Tags: java, multithreading, javafx, task, daemon

I have a large method with much logic that propably takes a while, so I start a Dialog with a ProgressBar to show the progress of the method. But if I press the button to start the method, nothing happens. After I tried to debug it, I found out that the Daemon-Thread gets suspended even before the task starts, and also, there is now Exception thrown.

Here is the code of everything that might be related to the problem, I wrote //logic inside on purpose, because the logic is about 300 lines long and not necessary:

```
public void getChat(String chat) {
        IntegerProperty prozentProcessing = new SimpleIntegerProperty();
        prozentProcessing.addListener(new ChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void changed(ObservableValue observable, Object oldValue, Object newValue) {
                Platform.runLater(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        mp.sA("Processing");
                        mp.sP(String.valueOf((int)newValue));
                        mp.isFortschrittDialogCompleted();
                    }
                });
            }
        });
        Task<Void> task = new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws Exception {
                //logic
            }
        };  
        this.task = task;
        mp.progressP().bind(this.task.progressProperty());
        mp.resetFortschrittDialog();
        mp.startFortschrittDialog();
        Thread t1 = new Thread(this.task);
        t1.setDaemon(true);
        t1.start();
        this.task.setOnSucceeded(e -> mp.endFortschrittDialog());   
    }
```

Here are also the class "MyRootPane" (mp):

```
package application.gui;

import application.data.ChangeLanguage;
import application.handler.MyHandler;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.Menu;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuBar;
import javafx.scene.control.MenuItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class MyRootPane extends BorderPane {

    private FortschrittDialog fd;
    private MyHandler mh;

    public MyRootPane() {
        mh = new MyHandler(this, primaryStage);
        fd = new FortschrittDialog(mh);
    }
    public void resetFortschrittDialog() {
        fd = new FortschrittDialog(mh);
    }
    public void startFortschrittDialog() {
        fd.show();
    }
    public void endFortschrittDialog() {
        fd.close();
    }
    public void isFortschrittDialogCompleted() {
        if(fd.isCompleted())
            endFortschrittDialog();
    }
    public DoubleProperty progressP() {
        return fd.getPBProgressProperty();
    }
    public StringProperty prozentP() {
        return fd.getProzentProperty();
    }
    public void sP(String p) {
        fd.setProzent(p);
    }
    public void sA(String a) {
        fd.setAnzeige(a);
    }
}
```

the class "FortschrittDialog" (fd):

```
package application.gui;

import application.handler.MyHandler;
import javafx.beans.property.DoubleProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.StringProperty;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonType;
import javafx.scene.control.Dialog;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.ButtonBar.ButtonData;
import javafx.scene.layout.FlowPane;
import javafx.util.Callback;

public class FortschrittDialog extends Dialog<Void> {

    private ProgressBar pb = new ProgressBar();
    private Label anzeige = new Label("Pending");
    private Label prozent = new Label(" - ");
    @SuppressWarnings("unused")
    private MyHandler mh;

    public FortschrittDialog(MyHandler mh) {
        this.mh = mh;
        FlowPane fp = new FlowPane();
        pb.setPrefWidth(500);
        pb.setProgress(-1f);
        fp.getChildren().addAll(pb, anzeige, prozent);
        ButtonType buttonTypeCancel = new ButtonType("Cancel", ButtonData.CANCEL_CLOSE);
        getDialogPane().getButtonTypes().addAll(buttonTypeCancel);
        getDialogPane().setContent(fp);
        this.setResultConverter(new Callback<ButtonType, Void>() {
            @Override
            public Void call(ButtonType b) {
                if(b == buttonTypeCancel) {
                    mh.abortTask();
                }
                return null;
            }
        });
    }
    public void setPBProgress(double progress) {
        pb.setProgress(progress);
    }
    public void setProzent(String prozent) {
        this.prozent.setText(prozent+"%");
    }
    public void setAnzeige(String anzeige) {
        this.anzeige.setText(anzeige+": ");
    }
    public DoubleProperty getPBProgressProperty() {
        return pb.progressProperty();
    }
    public StringProperty getProzentProperty() {
        return prozent.textProperty();
    }
    public boolean isCompleted() {
        if(pb.getProgress()==1.0) 
            return true;
        else return false;
    }
}
```

and last but not least "MyHandler" (mh):

```
public void abortTask() {
        kt.cT();
    }
```

kt is the class where the Task is executed.

I hope any of you can help me with this weird problem. And just for the record, I have a second method that is completely the same (except the logic in the call method of task) and in the second method it worked.

Comment: What is the exception that you are seeing "there is now Exception thrown" - have you checked that out?  t1.setOnFailed(err -> err.getSource().getException());

Comment: `Thread.suspend` is deprecated for a reason. Don't use it. Java shouldn't suspend your thread without you calling `suspend` yourself. Furthermore it's not safe to register the `onSuceeded` listener ***after*** starting the thread since you do not know if the seperate thread is done before registering the listener...

Comment: @purringpigeon, a .printStacktrace() at the end of the lambda would help :-)

Comment: @M.leRutte you are right - I missed the actual sys out...

Comment: Thank you all for your help. I tried printing the error message, but still, nothing happens. If I try debugging, the Thread is suspended from the very beginning, at some point Eclipse just says instead of a number for the line: not available. I also moved to .setOnSucceded but it didn't work. After I call `mp.resetFortschrittDialog();`/`mp.startFortschrittDialog();` at some point the program just ends, without even reaching `t1.start();` and without throwing an exception.

Comment: `task.setOnFailed(e -> task.getException().printStackTrace());` really shows nothing? (Obviously, you need to call this *before* you start the thread, and you should call `setOnSucceeded(...)` before you start the thread too.)

Comment: No, and I don't know why it should. As i mentioned, the program already stops working before the task gets started, somewhere between `mp.resetFortschrittDialog();` / `mp.startFortschrittDialog();` and I don't see why.